# Why does json.dump not call __getstate__

Tags: python

I have a python class which about the following contents, the important part is the ctypes library.

```
from ctypes import *

class PyClassExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = '/some/unix/path/file.so'
        self.lib = CDLL(self.path) # non-serializable element
        self.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] # serializable element

 def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()

        del state['lib']
        
        return state
```

When I try to call `json.dump` on an instantiated object of it I get an error message:

> TypeError: Object of type PyClassExample is not JSON serializable

Why does `json.dump` not call `__getstate__` but `pickle.dump` does call it? What mechanism does `json.dump` use to get the serializable state of an passed object?

Comment: By default `json.dump` uses [`JSONEncoder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/json/__init__.py#L172) class to serialize an object.

Answer (score 0):

The [protocol that includes `__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) was made for Pickle, which in turn was designed to be able to serialise pretty much any Python object. It is a flexible format which stores both an objects type and its state.

JSON doesn't have that. It only supports a fixed set of types, and extending the format is generally done by interpreting the values (like reading predefined keys in a `dict`) in a post-processing step. Here's how you can do that:

```
import json

def my_default(o):
    if isinstance(o, PyClassExample):
        return {'$type': 'PyClassExample', 'path': o.path, 'arr': o.arr}
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")

def my_object_hook(o):
    if o.get('$type') == 'PyClassExample':
        # FIXME: implement an __init__ that supports this
        return PyClassExample(o)
    return o
```

And then replace calls to `json.dump(...)` with `json.dump(..., default=my_default)` and calls to `json.load(...)` with `json.load(..., object_hook=my_object_hook)`.

If you want to support more classes you may want to make a more general solution, like a protocol that "JSON-able" classes follow. If you *really* want to, you could even abuse `__getstate__` for this, like so:

```
import json

# Make all classes you want to be able to serialise that need to use this mechanism a subclass of JSONAble
class JSONAble:
    registry = {}
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        JSONAble.registry[cls.__name__] = cls

def my_default(o):
    if isinstance(o, JSONAble):
        return {'(type)': type(o).__name__, **o.__getstate__()}
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")

def my_object_hook(o):
    if '(type)' in o:
        new_o = JSONAble.registry[o.pop('(type)')]()
        new_o.__dict__ = o
        return new_o
    return o
```